# Is it possible to open a Dialog window with Jelly Bean style with phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, dialog, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Please, I'd like to know how to create an window like this, but with something written or a loading indicator with phonegap:

http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8799/datepickerdialog411.png

I'm using cordova 2.5 and I've found some plugins, but it didn't work and the alert of phonegap is ugly and dark.

Plugins I've found:
- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WaitingDialog
- https: //gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/1336815

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize your alert either using `JavaScript` or by developing a `PhoneGap` Plugin.

1. Using `JavaScript`
   Use something like this : [Simple Model](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/#examples) or [Shadobox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/)
2. Using `PhoneGap` Plugin
   Use [PhoneGap Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html) to develop your own plugin for Alert Dialog and call that. Here you can use same `Jelly Bean Style` for your Custom Alert Dialog.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! :) I decided to do my own with JS and iSroll 4!